# Add Feature tool does not alow adding a polygon - just points

Tags: qgis, polygon

I've installed QGIS version 2.18.2 and want to create a polygon but the add feature tool only allows me to create points which are not linked to create a polygon. Looking at tutorials online, the add feature toolbar is a small green polygon shape. On my version it is 3 green dots (see image below).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When you create a new layer you have the option to select which type of geometry the new shape file becomes. Select "Polygon" to create polygons.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. I thought I had done this but must not have. Great, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to highlight the polygon layer in the layer panel then click the edit pencil button to start an edit session on this layer. The edit toolbar dynamically changes for whatever layer is highlighted/selected. I'm guessing you currently have a point layer highlighted/selected in the layer panel and this may be why you do not see the create polygon feature button.

Comment: Thanks very much. I thought I had done this but must not have. Great, thanks again.